# WordPress Scheduling Not Firing

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, task, scheduling

I want to echo a string after a time period using WordPress scheduling. Below is my code in functions.php. Nothing gets printed through echo statement and also there is no error. Please guide what am I doing wrong.

```
function add_new_intervals($schedules) {
    // add weekly and monthly intervals
    $schedules['now'] = array(
        'interval' => 1,
        'display' => __('Once Weekly')
    );

    return $schedules;
}

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_new_intervals');

function my_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ),'now', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function do_this_hourly() {
    echo "This is the Text";
}
```

Comment: Have the decency to ask on one site only first (and see what responses you get), instead of cross-posting to multiple ones. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221104/wordpress-scheduled-task-not-firing (or next time, be smart enough to leave out the “0 down vote favorite” part when copy&pasting from one SE site to another.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you are doing wrong is expecting to be able to see something echo when a cron job is run.  A better test would be to have it make a change in the database, something like:

```
`update_option('my_cron_test', current_time())`;
```

WP Cron jobs (like most cron jobs) are intended to run a function in the that needs to happen on a schedule.  They are not intended to create "user output".

**Some Tips with WP Cron Jobs:**
Your code will attempt to run that function once per hour, but the way WP is set up, it may (or may not) run, depending on if the site gets visited.

There are many solutions to this weakness, the simplest / most effective being to set up a crontab job on your server that triggers the WP cron. Something like so:

```
/15 * * * wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

For more help with this (it can be tricky), check out these articles:
[Properly Setting Up WP Cron Jobs](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/)
[Mastering WP Cron](http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-wordpress-cron/)